# Raw pointer implicitly converts to const pointer, need the same with user type

Tags: c++, templates, constants, implicit-conversion

If I have a template function accepting a pointer to the template type:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T* x);
```

it naturally accepts a pointer to a non-const object:

```
int* x = ...;
foo(x); //int* implicitly converted to const int *
```

I'd like to do the same with a template class which has pointer semantics.

For example, the recently proposed [array_view](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3851.pdf) class, which is a view on a contiguous block of memory, has (non-owning) pointer semantics and can be used to refer an array of mutable or const items:

```
array_view<int> av = ...;
av[0] = 1;
array_view<const int> cav = ...;
cav[0] = 1; // <- error: read-only variable is not assignable
```

The problem is that the pattern above with the raw pointer does not work:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(array_view<const T> x);
...
array_view<int> x;
foo(x); // <- error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
```

Even if I add copy constructor or conversion operators which convert between the `T` and `const T` variants the compiler is unable to resolve the `T` for the template.

I'm aware of 2 workarounds:

- explicitly specify the template parameter at call: `foo<int>(x)`
- write a more general template: `template<typename U> void foo(U x)` and maybe constrain `U` with metaprogramming.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use

```
template <typename T>
void foo(std::array_view<T> x);
```

Interestingly, that works for both forms of array views:

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
foo(array_view<int>(std::begin(array), std::end(array)));
foo(array_view<int const>(std::begin(array), std::end(array)));
```

The `const`-ness of the argument is implicitly enforced by the `const`-ness of the argument. The same is, BTW, true for pointer arguments if the pointee type is deduced:

```
template <typename T>
void bar(T*);
```

When `bar()` is called with an `int const*` the type `T` is deduced as `T const`. The primary need for the `const` version is when the type is already deduced but the argument should fit. However, in that case the `std::array_view<...>` conversion would similarly work.

Comment: I would still miss the `const` keyword: it provides a promise for the caller. But hey, let's introduce a new type on the first line of `foo`: `using C = std::add_const<T>::type`. With this addition this answer seems to be the best workaround so I'm accepting it.

Comment: @tamas.kenez: A `static_assert()` wouldn't make much sense: you probably want to accept an `array_view<T>` with a non-`const` qualified `T`. The implementation just wouldn't modify any the `T`s (unless, of course, any of the presumed to be `const` functions happens not to be `const` for the specific `T`). If you feel you need to make a promise you'd forward the implementation to a function which is `const` qualified and explicitly specify the argument while forwarding the call.

Comment: I mentioned `static_assert` in my first comment. I also found that it's of no use so I edited the comment before your comment.